Face built from boxes - geometry nodes
I would like to create a face built from the boxes like the reference attached below. 
I was experimenting with the geometry nodes - mesh to volume (grid) but it gives totally different effect.
With the method - distribute points on face I don't know how to achieve the regular distribution without any gaps and overlapping shapes.
Does anyone know how to achieve the effect of geometric face like the reference I have attached?
I would be grateful for any suggestions.
